# How to make connection with 2 DBs while using mongo official driver for node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Am trying to make the connection from node js to Mongo DB.
while using mongo's official node js driver [Official](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)
I am able to make a connection with DB at one at a time.
but am looking for a way to get connected with 2 DBs at a time.
for a fallback issue.

**Approach one:**

```
const MONGO_CLIENT = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const MONGO_URL = mongodb://USER:PASS@HOST:PORT/DBNAME

MONGO_CLIENT.connect(MONGO_URL, (err: any, db: any) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(503).send(err);
  }
  console.log ('Connected do the things');
}
```

I got success by this way.
but am looking for a fallback way.
while setting two Hosts in URL I got errors

```
const MONGO_URL = mongodb://USER:PASS@PRIMARY_HOST:PRIMARY_HOST_PORT,SECONDARY_HOST:SECONDARY_HOST_PORT/DBNAME
```

am getting following errors

```
{
"name":"MongoError",
"message":"seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name"
}
```

Could anyone please explain to me what am doing wrong. and how should I connect with multiple DBS?

NOTE: Primary and secondary DBs are same and always synched.

Comment: are the member of replice set ? and same replice set ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Same

Comment: try adding `{
        replicaSet: 'nameOfReplicaSet'
    }` as options to `connect(..`

Comment: something like `.connect('url1', 'url2', {replicaSet : 'nameOfReplica''})`